# How do I get HTML of an object in App Lab?

Tags: javascript, app-lab

I'm using Code.org's App Lab to make a chatroom, and the chat messages are shown using the innerHTML() function.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the inner HTML of an object.

I've tried assigning the HTML to a variable, such as `html`, and when `html` is updated, the inner HTML of chatArea is updated as well:

```
var html;
onRecordEvent("Messages", {}, function (rec) {
  html = html + "<div style='background: white; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px'><div><b>" + rec.username + "</b></div><div>" + rec.message + "</div></div>";
  innerHTML("chatArea", html);
});
```

However, this requires that chatArea is empty at first, otherwise it will be emptied the first time `html` is edited.

Is there any way to get the innerHTML of an object, since `document` is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see this being done is by using tampermonkey or some script to fetch it from the actual source.

I haven't seen anything on getting the html either so I'm sorry there. Also you can just send the messages to a textarea without html.

*A little bit off-track*, you can create a record every time a new chat is sent then ever so often loop thru the chat records to see what new chats should be added. *This is a tadbit of code I always use for my chat screens for the Dungeon Destiny games.*

```js
//chat info
go("goChat", "warnChat");
go("acceptWarn", "chatt");
go("backChat", "home");
 

sayCS('home', 'announcements');
sayCS('warnChat', 'warnTxt');
sayCS('tosLog', 'tosLogTxt');
sayCS('tos', 'tosTxt');

function sayCS(scr, text){
  onEvent(scr, "keydown", function(event){
    if(event.key=='Alt'){
      playSpeech(getText(text), "female", "English (UK)");
    }
  });
}

onEvent("chatt", "keydown", function(event){
  if(event.key=="Enter"){
    if (getText("setMessage")==''||null) {
      setProperty("setMessage", "placeholder", "Please Type Something Before You Send It");
      setTimeout(function() {
        setProperty("setMessage", "placeholder", "Type A Message Here");
      }, 2000);
    } else if(getText("setMessage")!=''||null) {
        if(username != '' ||null){
          createRecord("chat", {from: username, message:(getText("setMessage"))}, function(){});
        } else if(username == '' ||null){
            createRecord("chat", {from: username, message:(getText("setMessage"))}, function(){});
        }
    }
    setText("setMessage", "");
  }
});

var messages;
function setChat() {
  messages=[];
  readRecords("chat", {}, function(records) {
    for (var i =0; i < records.length; i++) {
      if(!records[i].message.includes("fuck")){
        appendItem(messages,(records[i]).from+ ": "+(records[i]).message);
      }
      }
    messages.reverse();
    setText("chat", messages.join("\n"));
  });
}
```